# Octave: How can I fit a sinusoid to my data using Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, data-fitting, trigonometry

My goal is to fit a sinusoid to data goming from a datalogger using Octave.
The datalogger logs force which is produced using an excenter, so it theoretically should be a sine wave.

I could not find any hint on how to do this elsewhere.

Currently I'm using the function "splinefit" followd by "ppval" to fit my data but I don't realy get the results I hoped from it...
Has anybody an idea how I could fit a sinusoid to my data?

Here's my current code I use to fit the data and a scrennshot of the result:

```
## splinefit force left
spfFL = splinefit(XAxis,forceL,50);    
fitForceL=ppval(spfFL,XAxis);

##middle force left
meanForceL=mean(fitForceL);
middleedForceL=fitForceL-meanForceL;
```

result spline fit

[image]

on the X-Axis I have the 30'000 measurepoints or logs

on the Y-Axis I have the actual measured force values

the data comes from the datalogger in a .csv-file like this

[image]

Comment: sounds like a xy-problem. What do you really want to do? Is it possible that you just want to obtain the frequency of your sampled value (and perhaps also amplitude and phase)? See FFT for this and perhaps period measurement with zero crossing. And please please please add your data verbatim and never ever add code or data as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a least squares optimization, using `fminsearch`

```
% sine to fit (in your case your data)
x = 0:0.01:50;
y = 2.6*sin(1.2*x+3.1) + 7.3 + 0.2*rand(size(x)); % create some noisy sine with known parameters

% function with parameters
fun = @(x,p) p(1)*sin(p(2)*x+p(3)) + p(4);  % sine wave with 4 parameters to estimate
fcn = @(p) sum((fun(x,p)-y).^2);            % cost function to minimize the sum of the squares

% initial guess for parameters
p0 = [0 0 0 0];

% parameter optimization
par = fminsearch(fcn, p0);

% see if estimated parameters match measured data
yest = fun(x, par)
plot(x,y,x,yest)
```

Replace `x` and `y` with your data. The `par` variable contains the parameters of the sine, as defined in `fun`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your imediat answer! I tryed to implement it but the aplitude of the sinus is way to small and the frequency is way to high. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could change the initial guess `p0` to some values closer to what you expect the frequency and amplitude to be. In this case, since you already have the mean and peak to peak amplitude, you could omit these from the parameter estimation or set the initial guess values accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a simple regression using the sine and cosine of your (time) input as your regression features.

Here's an example

```matlab
% Let's generate a dataset from a known sinusoid as an example
N       = 1000;
Range   = 100;
w       = 0.25; % known frequency (e.g. from specs or from fourier analysis)
Inputs  = randi(Range, [N, 1]);
Targets = 0.5 * sin( w * Inputs + pi/3 ) + 0.05 * randn( size( Inputs ) );

% Y = A + B sin(wx) + C cos(wx);    <-- this is your model
Features = [ ones(N, 1), sin(w * Inputs), cos(w * Inputs) ];
Coefs    = pinv(Features) * Targets;
A = Coefs(1); % your solutions
B = Coefs(2); 
C = Coefs(3);

% print your nice solution against the input dataset
figure('position', [0, 0, 800, 400])
ax1 = axes()
plot(Inputs, Targets, 'o', 'markersize', 10, ...
                           'markeredgecolor', [0, 0.25, 0.5], ...
                           'markerfacecolor', [0, 0.5, 1], ...
                           'linewidth', 1.5)
set(ax1, 'color', [0.9, 0.9, 0.9])
ax2 = axes()
X = 1:0.1:Range;
plot( X, A + B*sin(w * X) + C*cos(w * X), 'k-', 'linewidth', 5 ); hold on
plot( X, A + B*sin(w * X) + C*cos(w * X), 'g-', 'linewidth', 2 ); hold off
set(ax2, 'xlim', get(ax1, 'xlim'), 'ylim', get(ax1, 'ylim'), 'color', 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: PS. Note that you can always go back from your Bsin(x) + Ccos(x) coefficients to a single sine using standard trigonometric identities (http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/252/lc-trig.pdf)

Comment: Thank's for your answer! This might be a stupid question but I'm pretty new to this topic... Where exactly do I put my imput X and Y in your solution?

Comment: @S.Hug Replace `Inputs` with your inputs (i.e. `X`, the timepoints), and `Targets` with the targets (i.e. `Y`, your signal) that you're trying to fit a model to. And `N` with the number of observations.

Comment: This assume the pulsation is `1`, as in `wt=t`. Any way the pulsation/period could be determined from your method ?

Comment: @Hoki thanks for pointing that out, I meant to mention it and forgot! From the nature of the problem it sounds like the frequency would be known; but if not, personally I would simply obtain it first from a fourier analysis of the raw signal and plug it in directly, rather than perform a separate optimisation for it.